# SQL Injection Tools

Tags: php, sql, firefox-addon, sql-injection

I currently use firefox SQL Inject Me - to test for form data SQL Injection, Is there any tools that tests the same but for dynamic Sites i.e. URL querystrings.

Comment: Sure. Point us to the URL in question :P

Comment: There are definitely tools out there that automate this - I used to use one and am racking my brain for the name. If nobody else suggests it soon, I'll go dig out some old emails.

Comment: Basiclife - that would be great if you could look :-)

Comment: Did you find it then?? Or you not replying?

Answer (score 1):

Using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) properly should eliminate need for sql injection testing.

I know this isn't the direct answer to your question, but I do hope you have control over code that you're testing, because your problem will disappear if you use prep. statements instead of using regular ones with string concatenation.

---

*Disclaimer*: I've never written a line of PHP code in my life, so if I've messed up this answer horifficaly; I'd be glad to hear more opinions.

Comment: Yeah appreciate that, I do need a tool though, Just so i can prove something to a client then demonstrate how to fix it.. Just to put it in perspective really.

Answer (score 1):

[sqlninja](http://sqlninja.sourceforge.net) - didn't used myself, but looks like tool you`re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [sqlmap](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage) for automated check, although you should get familiar with the techniques used to be able to solve de problem and avoid it in the future.